# How can I show only custom fields with values while hiding those with no value and their corresponding CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

**UPDATE: When I deactivated the LightSpeed Cash plugin, the problem is fixed! But how I can solve the problem without deactivating the plugin???**

I have 3 custom fields freeware, trial and apk each with its CSS, now I want only the custom fields which have values to show up and which don't have values don't show up completely (With their CSS).

https://softcroco.com/download-shareit-apk/

[Screenshot of the issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR9Fe.png)

In the URL above freeware and apk CFs have value and trial doesn't has value and still it's CSS appear and then disappear when I open or refresh the page!

I want to make custom fields which don't have values don't appear completely!

My Code:

```
                                <span class="freeware"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'freeware', true); ?></span>
                                <span class="apk"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'apk', true); ?></span> 
                                <span class="trial"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'trial', true); ?></span>
```

```
<script> const author = document.querySelector('.author'); const freeware = document.querySelector('.freeware'); const apk = document.querySelector('.apk'); const trial = document.querySelector('.trial'); if (author.textContent.trim() === '') {author.remove(); } if (freeware.textContent.trim() === '') { freeware.remove(); } if (apk.textContent.trim() === '') { apk.remove(); } if (trial.textContent.trim() === '') { trial.remove(); } </script>
```

```
.freeware { align-items: center; border: 1px solid rgba(38,153,251,.25); border-radius: 24px; color: #2699fb; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600; justify-content: center; padding: 0px 10px; border: 1px solid rgba(83,204,39,.25); color: #fff!important; background: #018660; margin-left: -5px;}.apk { align-items: center; border: 1px solid rgba(38,153,251,.25); border-radius: 24px; color: #ff003b; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600; justify-content: center; padding: 0px 10px; border: 1px solid #ff003b; color: #fff!important; background: #ff003b; margin-left: -5px; }.trial { align-items: center; border: 1px solid rgba(38,153,251,.25); border-radius: 24px; color: #ff003b; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600; justify-content: center; padding: 0px 10px; border: 1px solid #ff003b; color: #fff!important; background: #ff003b; margin-left: -5px; } .freeware, .apk, .trial { font-family: 'Roboto Slab'; font-size: 13px;} .infosoftware { display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: -5px; }
```

A lot of CSS changes!

Comment: Can you clarify or provide me with the code so I can add or modify

Comment: I provide JavaScript and CSS of the custom fields.

Comment: Sorry, i had to delete my comment because i think i didn't get the issue right =)

Comment: No problem :) Do you have a fix for this problem?

Comment: The orange line that is visible while the page is loading disappears as soon as the social media links and ads appear. I suspect the color line is not coming from the "trial" as you think. Also, the CSS for those social media buttons contains what I assume is your incorrect attempt to comment out a declaration, which is causing the rest of the declarations in the rule to be considered invalid (as viewed in Developer Tools). `.at-resp-share-element .at-share-btn { }` contains `*display:inline;*`; correct way to comment out: `/* display:inline; */`

Comment: I applied the code and it doesn't work! Note: the problem disappears when I logged in WordPress, I think it is caused by LightCash plugin!

Comment: I think the orange line is coming from the "trial"

Comment: UPDATE: When I deactivated the LightSpeed Cash plugin, the problem is fixed! But how I can solve the problem without deactivating the plugin???

Answer (score 1):

If the element is truly empty, with no whitespace, you could do something like this:

```css
.freeware:empty, 
.apk:empty, 
.trial:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work!